# Wix Copy If Not Exists

Tags: wix

I have several folders files included in my Wix based installer. One of the folders may exist on the target machine already outside of any MSI installation. I do not want to replace the folder or files if they already exist for just one of the folders. It might be OK to not replace the files if they are older. Is there anything I need to specify or is this the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive answer is in the MSI SDK here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. What about on uninstall, I don't necessarily want to remove the folder/files that are part of the installer if it existed prior. Any way to a not remove just one folder while removing the others?

Comment: To leave files behind, put them in a Component/@Permanent="yes".